# How to capture photo via HP or tablet and automatically upload it using PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Can you help me with this problem? I want to make program in PHP and use Jquery mobile. I want it to capture a photo from the device's camera.

What method or function can I use?  A php library or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you are mentioning multiple programming languages here. `Javascript` is a client side language (which means it will run straight from the user's device). `PHP` is a server side scripting language (which means you have no control of the code, and it must be run on a server).

Secondly, from my knowledge, it's not yet possible to have access to a device's camera using Javascript in a browser. You will have to make use of a device's native functions. I recommend reading about PhoneGap library. [PhoneGap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_media_capture_capture.md.html) will simplify what you want to do, and will reduce the amount of learning time you will need to spend writing an app for each device, as code is very similar across multiple platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the camera without an application on the device.

With some devices, like Android, you can have an upload file field in an HTML form that can access the users photo gallery (pictures they have already taken). All iSheep products (iphone, ipad) prevent this access however and **require** an application for this.

```
<form ...>
<input type="file"/>
...
</form>
```

I second the use of PhoneGap to help with creating the application. You will be able to write javascript that runs on the device. You will have to create apps for **each** type of device however.

Comment: I have been trying to use the phonegap, but until now, I still confuses. I Try to googling some tutorial for fix this problem.<br><br>  Can you help me to find address for good tutorial?  the device is advance fandroid with gingerbread OS. the application is using PHP and run in the browser, can it take picture from the tablet camera?

Comment: did you look at Phonegap's documentation **at all**? There's a **full** example of how to use [the camera](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html#Camera)